# Delete duplicates, and reassign FK value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

```
 Table1: 
 [id], [ColA]

 Table2: 
 [id], [Table1Id]
```

A previous update caused duplicates in Table1 and those duplicates to be assocated with rows in Table2.  It looks like this in the db:

```
Table1
1, 89
2, 89

Table2
6, 1
7, 2
```

I would like to delete the duplicates and reassign the value of the `Table2.Table1Id` to the one `Table1.id` row that should be left.  Is this possible in a single statement?  Ive seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows) on how to delete all but one, but I am lost on how to reassign the `Table2.Table1Id` value.

edit: 
 The end result should look like this:

```
Table1
2, 89

Table2
6, 2
7, 2
```

Comment: so the values in table1.cola are also unique?

Comment: No, ColA represents the duplicates I'm trying to get rid of, but yes, once I delete the duplicates, it should be unique as well.

Comment: What I meant was when it's all fixed ColA will be unique

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists dbo.Table2;
drop table if exists dbo.Table1;

create table dbo.Table1 (
ID int primary key
, ColA int
);

create table dbo.Table2 (
ID int
, Table1ID int
);

alter table dbo.Table2
add constraint FK_Table2_Table1
foreign key (Table1ID)
references dbo.Table1 (ID);

insert into dbo.Table1 (ID, ColA)
values (1, 89), (2, 89);

insert into dbo.Table2 (ID, Table1ID)
values (6, 1), (7, 2);

drop table if exists #temp;

select
ttt.ID
into #temp
from (
select
    t.ID
    , t.ColA
    , ROW_NUMBER() over (order by t.ID) as Rbr
from dbo.Table1 t
    inner join (
        select
            t.ColA
        from dbo.Table1 t
        group by t.ColA
        having COUNT (t.ID) > 1
    ) tt on t.ColA = tt.ColA
) ttt
where ttt.Rbr > 1

update t2
set
Table1ID = t1i.ID
from #temp t
inner join dbo.Table2 t2 on t.ID = t2.Table1ID
inner join dbo.Table1 t1 on t.ID = t1.ID
inner join dbo.Table1 t1i on t1.ColA = t1i.ColA
        and t1i.ID not in (select t.ID from #temp t)

delete t1
from #temp t
inner join dbo.Table1 t1 on t.ID = t1.ID

select
*
from dbo.Table1 t

select
*
from dbo.Table2 t
```